# Is there a function to inflate a Rectangle?

Tags: graphics

From `FindFaces` I have a set of `Rectangles` of the form

> Rectangle[{x1,y1},{x2,y2}]

I want to inflate those by a certain percentage. I can calculate the new corners using `RegionCentroid`, but I was wondering if Mathematica has a built-in function for this, something like

> InflateRectangle[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}, percentage]

so that e.g. {{100,100},{200,300}} inflated by 20% would become {{90,80},{210,320}}.

Comment: I think `Scale[Rectangle[{100, 100}, {200, 300}], 1.2]` does what you're looking for. It scales with the center of the bounding box of the rectangle held fixed.

Comment: @Simon - That's it. Thanks a bunch!